# Custom Search not working

Tags: custom-post-types, php, taxonomy, search

I'm trying to create a custom search that uses two dropdowns only (no text input). The first dropdown lists custom post types, the second lists the "location" taxonomy. [This](http://paste.ofcode.org/WSyw4ZdeLweEicQQFj9aPG) is my code so far (submitted on POC for easier reading:

Comment: Thank you taking readability in to account, but it is more useful if you add code directly to your post. The reason behind this is, if that link ever dies, your question is useless to the site and everyone else, as all of your context lies in that dead link. Please file an [edit] and add your code directly to your post. Thank you

Comment: Sure, I will remember that, thanks:) I managed to figure out the problem, I had forgotten to add a value to the options :$